# Run Python Script based on Watchdog once files in folder

Tags: python, automation, watchdog, python-watchdog

I would like run my python script once a file in a certain folder is modified. To do this, I chose Watchdog.

First, I created an own project folder on my local machine and created and activated a venv.
The following python script is also in the same folder which gets monitored.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import pandas as pd

def on_modified(event):
    print("modified")
    test()


def test():
    print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Watchdog_test'
    event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()

    event_handler.on_modified = on_modified

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        print("monitoring")
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print("Done")
    observer.join()
```

This is a easy example code but it shows the issue I have.
So the code basically works and once I modify a file in the folder, I get "modified" in the terminal.
Unfortunately, this does not trigger the function test(). In my real code I do the same but then trigger another function with triggers each function, like:

```
def on_modified(event):
    print("modified")
    trigger_all_functions()

def trigger_all_functions():
    function1(...)
    ... = function2(...)
```

and so on

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me on Linux and `watchdog==3.0.0`.

Comment: (Tangentially, code you put in `if __name__ == '__main__':` should be trivial; the purpose of this boilerplate is to allow you to import the code, which you will not want to do anyway if the logic you need is not available via import. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188) ,

Comment: I tried again without using the main function as the py.file don't need to be imported from some other python file. Not it works! So solution is the same code besides the if __name__ == '__main__':